# what is difference between (ulimit -s unlimited) and (export KMP_STACKSIZE = xx)?

Tags: fortran, openmp, intel, ulimit, stack-size

I ran my program like below, and used ( `ulimit -s unlimited` ).
It works.

```
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(1024,2,1541) :: L_X TanV
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(4) :: Val_X, Val_Y
    REAL(DP), dimension(1029) :: E_x
    REAL(DP), dimension(1024) :: E_y
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(1024,1024) :: E_Fx, E_Fy

    !$OMP SECTIONS PRIVATE(i, j, ii,jj, PSL_X, i_x, i_y, Val_X, Val_Y)
    !$OMP SECTION
    do j=1,LinkPlusBndry
      do i=1,Kmax(j)-1
        PSL_X(1)=modulo(L_X(i,1,j),H*N2); PSL_X(2)=L_X(i,2,j)
        i_x=floor(PSL_X(1)/H)+2; i_y=floor(PSL_X(2)/H)
        call Delta4((E_x(i_x:i_x+3)-PSL_X(1))/H,Val_X)
        call Delta4((E_y(i_y:i_y+3)-PSL_X(2))/H,Val_Y)
        do ii=1,4; do jj=1,4
           EE_Fx(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1)=EE_Fx(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1) &
                                   +tauH2*TanV(i,1,j)*Val_X(jj)*Val_Y(ii)
        end do; end do
      end do
    end do

    ...
    ...
    ...

    !$OMP SECTION
    do j=1,LinkPlusBndry
      do i=1,Kmax(j)-1
        PSL_X(1)=modulo(L_X(i,1,j),H*N2); PSL_X(2)=L_X(i,2,j)
        i_x=floor(PSL_X(1)/H)+2; i_y=floor(PSL_X(2)/H)
        call Delta4((E_x(i_x:i_x+3)-PSL_X(1))/H,Val_X)
        call Delta4((E_y(i_y:i_y+3)-PSL_X(2))/H,Val_Y)
        do ii=1,4; do jj=1,4
           EE_Fy(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1)=EE_Fy(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1) &
                                   +tauH2*TanV(i,2,j)*Val_X(jj)*Val_Y(ii)
        end do; end do
      end do
    end do
    !$OMP END SECTIONS
```

I don't like using `!$OMP SECTION`, it restricts the speed by using only 2 threads.

So I had changed my code like below.

```
!$OMP DO PRIVATE(j, i, PSL_X, i_x, i_y, ii, jj, Val_X, Val_Y) REDUCTION(+:EE_Fx, EE_Fy)
do j=1,LinkPlusBndry
  do i=1,Kmax(j)-1
    PSL_X(1)=modulo(L_X(i,1,j),H*N2); PSL_X(2)=L_X(i,2,j)
    i_x=floor(PSL_X(1)/H)+2; i_y=floor(PSL_X(2)/H)
    call Delta4((E_x(i_x:i_x+3)-PSL_X(1))/H,Val_X)
    call Delta4((E_y(i_y:i_y+3)-PSL_X(2))/H,Val_Y)
    do ii=1,4; do jj=1,4
       EE_Fx(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1)=EE_Fx(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1) &
                               +tauH2*TanV(i,1,j)*Val_X(jj)*Val_Y(ii)
       EE_Fy(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1)=EE_Fy(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1) &
                               +tauH2*TanV(i,2,j)*Val_X(jj)*Val_Y(ii)
    end do; end do

    PSL_X(1)=modulo(L_X(i+1,1,j),H*N2); PSL_X(2)=L_X(i+1,2,j)
    i_x=floor(PSL_X(1)/H)+2; i_y=floor(PSL_X(2)/H)
    call Delta4((E_x(i_x:i_x+3)-PSL_X(1))/H,Val_X)
    call Delta4((E_y(i_y:i_y+3)-PSL_X(2))/H,Val_Y)
    do ii=1,4; do jj=1,4
       EE_Fx(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1)=EE_Fx(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1) &
                               -tauH2*TanV(i,1,j)*Val_X(jj)*Val_Y(ii)
       EE_Fy(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1)=EE_Fy(i_y+ii-1,i_x+jj-1) &
                               -tauH2*TanV(i,2,j)*Val_X(jj)*Val_Y(ii)
    end do; end do
  end do
end do
!$OMP END DO
```

when I launch this code, I get segmentation fault.

I thought it was related with the memory size.
So, after searching I found this solution

```
 export KMP_STACKSIZE=value
```

Now I use 2 different commands

```
 ulimit -s unlimited
```

and

```
 export KMP_STACKSIZE=value
```

It works well, but I don't know difference between the two commands.
What is the difference?

Comment: We have too little details to know what is really happening with `ulimit -s`. At least you should tell us what is your operating system (distribution and version) and what is your compiler (version) and which error so you get. Also you should say, which `value` do you use for `KMP_STACKSIZE` and if this variaable has any value even before you used the `export`.

Comment: I use intelcompiler, centOS 7 and KMP_STACKSIZE=1g. i didn't know a default value what it was. I'm Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ulimit` sets the OS limits for the program.

`KMP_STACKSIZE` tells the OpenMP implementation about how much stack to *actually* allocate for each of the stacks.  So, depending on your OS defaults you might need both.  BTW, you should rather use `OMP_STACKSIZE` instead, as `KMP_STACKSIZE` is the environment variable used by the Intel and clang compilers.  `OMP_STACKSIZE` is the standard way of setting the stack size of the OpenMP threads.

Note, that this problem is usually more exposed, as Fortran tends to keep more data on the stack, esp. arrays.  Some compilers can move such arrays to the heap automatically, see for instance `-heap-arrays` for the Intel compiler.